# incrementing a string. (JS or PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, regex

i would like to know if it's possible to do this in javascript or php or anything.

i want to make an invoice number that starts with 001000, now to get the next invoice number i need to increment it by adding `1`, but when i tried to do it in php. it just converts it to a number, which is not good because i need the `00` prefix. and in javascript. it just add the `1` to the end.

i know it could be done using regex but i don't know how.

EDIT: here's the invoice sequence i want to achieve.

- 001000
- 001001
- 001002

and when it reached to `009999` it should be `010000`

please help.

**SOLVED**:
i used str_pad as spencer said. 
`php
$last_invoice = Quote::all()->last()->invoice + 1; // to convert it to number.
str_pad( ($last_invoice, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // fill 0 prefix.`

Comment: can you share the invoice number sequence you are expecting and logic to increment every number?

Comment: Why not increment a normal int, then string pad it?

Comment: `sprintf('%02d', $value);` or `str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` Where `$value` contains the integer you want to increase without leading zeros. These will take of that after it. You can use an if-statement like `if($value > 9999){ sprintf('%01d', $value); }` etc for higher numbers.

Comment: @SpencerMay i haven't checked the docs yet. but i'll give it a try. thanks!

Comment: @SpencerMay, can you put your comment into answer? so i can mark it as answer.
good thing i search for str_pad. :D

Comment: Feel free to post your "solved" section as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used str_pad as @spencermay said.  php
$last_invoice = Quote::all()->last()->invoice + 1; // to convert it to number.
str_pad( ($last_invoice, 6, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // fill 0 prefix.

Answer (score 2):

You can store the invoice number as an actual number, not a string, in order to easily increment it. When you print the number for display, pass it with leading zeros.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this logic

```js
var currentNumber = "000100";
var nextNumber = "00" + String( Number( currentNumber ) + 1 ).slice( 0 , 6 );
console.log(nextNumber);
```

Convert this into a function

```js
function nextInSequence( currentNumber )
{
  return "00" + String( Number( currentNumber ) + 1 ).slice( 0 , 6 );
}
var currentNumber = "000100";
currentNumber = nextInSequence( currentNumber );
console.log( currentNumber )
currentNumber = nextInSequence( currentNumber );
console.log( currentNumber )
currentNumber = nextInSequence( currentNumber );
console.log( currentNumber )
```

Comment: @Hitori Javascript doesn't actually have a native function for string padding. This answer is the correct way to achieve this in JS. `str_pad` would be your "goto" in PHP

Comment: @SpencerMay yes. i used PHP

Comment: What if there are 5 non-zero digits? I think the OP only wants one leading zero in such a case.